# Need help identifying what is written on the banknote

Tags: translation

Can you please tell me what denomination this banknote is and what year? Thank you!

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

点钞券 = Banknotes counting ticket

出纳点钞专用券 = "paper money counting note, exclusively for cashier"

练功专用 =  exclusively for practice

严禁流通 =  Strictly prohibited for circulating

It is not a real banknote, it is a note created for the cashiers to practice counting money.

They didn't want the cashiers to use real money to practice counting money. So they gave them fake ones instead. And it is strictly prohibited to pass it as real banknote.

*I presume these practice notes are the same size, used the same paper as real banknote, also looked similar to the real thing. Must had been used before banknotes counting machine appeared*

Comment: So, it is not a counterfeit, but a counterfake? :)

Comment: Thank you very much!